# Simplify this formula

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, sumproduct

The following formula is working, but I feel like it could be simplified somehow. Does anyone know how?

To explain what it's doing, it looks at the range B1:F2, and it looks at the numbers only. Then it finds the delta of each number to the number 7 and adds all deltas together.

How can it be simplified?

Here's the formula. It's an array, so I press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter it.

> `=SUMPRODUCT(--IF(ISNUMBER(B1:F2),1),B1:F2)-SUMPRODUCT(--IF(ISNUMBER(B1:F2),1))*7`

Here is the data:
[image]

Comment: `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:F2),B1:F2-7,0))`

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As jblood94 commented:

> =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:F2),B1:F2-7,0))